# UPDATE: JavaScript code is displaying as child node

Tags: javascript, xml, html, document.write

**SOLUTION:** I figured it out. I used jQuery instead of JavaScript with a little help from zohodiscussions.com.

```
Ajax Google plugin:  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js

**js. file:**
function form_input_classes() {

    jQuery('input[type="text"]').addClass('text');
    jQuery('input[type="password"]').addClass('text');
    jQuery('input[type="checkbox"]').addClass('checkbox');
    jQuery('input[type="radio"]').addClass('radiobutton');
    jQuery('input[type="submit"]').addClass('submit');
    jQuery('input[type="image"]').addClass('buttonImage');

}
function form_labelize() { jQuery(".labelize input:text").clearingInput(); }


var version = jQuery.browser.version;

if (version instanceof Object) { version = version.number(); }

function loadXMLDoc(XMLname) {
    return jQuery.ajax({ async: false, url: XMLname }).responseXML;
}
xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("demo.xml");
var M = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("rotatingImages");
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('script').remove()
    form_input_classes();
    form_labelize();
    var pauseClicked = function () {
        jQuery('#cycle').cycle('pause');
        jQuery('#play').attr("style", "display:block");
        jQuery('#pause').attr("style", "display:none");
        jQuery('#pause').removeClass("active");
        return false;
    };
    var playClicked = function () {
        jQuery('#cycle').cycle('resume');
        jQuery('#pause').attr("style", "display:block");
        jQuery('#play').attr("style", "display:none");
        jQuery('#pause').addClass("active");
        return false;
    };
    jQuery('#play').attr("style", "display:none");
    jQuery('#pause').attr("style", "display:block");
    jQuery('#pause').click(pauseClicked);
    jQuery('#play').click(playClicked);
    jQuery("#slideNavigation a").focus(function () {
        jQuery(this).blur();
    });


    jQuery('#cycle').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        speed: 1000,
        timeout: 5000,
        prev: '#prev',
        next: '#next',
        pager: '#hero-nav ul ',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function (idx, slide) {
            return '#hero-nav li:eq(' + idx + ') a.page';
        }
    });

})


**HTML references:**
<div id="content" class="clearfix home">
  <div id="hero">
    <div id='rotator'>
      <div id='cycle' class='clearfix'>
       <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(M).find('image').each(function (i, img) {
        document.write("<img src='" + jQuery(img).text() + "' />");
        })
       </script>
      </div>
    </div>

     <!--end-rotating-images-->
       <div id="hero-cycle" class="clearfix">
        <div id="hero-nav">
         <ul>
          <script type="text/javascript">
           jQuery(M).each(function (i, item){
           document.write("<li class='hero-text'>");
           document.write("<div class='hero-info clearfix'>");
           document.write("<a href='" +
     jQuery(item).find('filePath').text() + "' target='_blank'>" +
     jQuery(item).find('description').text()
     + "</a>");
           document.write("</div>")
           document.write("<a class='page' href='#'></a></li>")
          })
          </script>

      </ul>
      <div id="annc_controls">
         <a href="#" id="play">
         <img src="images/blue_play.gif" alt="Play" border="0" style="vertical-align: text-bottom"/></a>
         <a href="#" id="pause">
         <img src="images/blue_pause.gif" alt="Stop" border="0" style="vertical-align: text-bottom"/>
         </a>
      </div>
      <!--<div id="slideNavigation"></div>-->
      </div>
      <!-- /#hero-nav -->
      </div>
      <!-- /#hero-cycle -->
      </div>
      <!-- /#hero -->
      </div>
```

I updated my code and the rotating images are inline with the description. The only problem I have is the javascript loads first in place of a 1st image. There are only 3 images and the code displays firs then image #1 and so on. Is this a browser issue with ActiveXObject and IE 9? I'm having a similar issue with FireFox latest version. Nothing shows in this browser. Any help? –

.html file:

```
<head><script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function loadXMLDoc(XMLname)
    //
    {
        var xmlDoc;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlDoc = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlDoc.open("GET", XMLname, false);
            xmlDoc.send("");
            return xmlDoc.responseXML;
        }
        // IE 5 and IE 6

        else if (ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")) {
            xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            xmlDoc.async = false;
            xmlDoc.load(XMLname);
            return xmlDoc;
        }
        alert("Error loading document!");
        return null;
    }


    xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("demo.xml");

    var M = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("rotatingImages");

    //-->

</script>
</head>
<div id="hero">
  <div id='rotator'>
   <div id='cycle' class='clearfix'>
     <script type="text/javascript">
      for (i = 0; i < M.length; i++) {
      document.write("<img src='" + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("image")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "' />");
      }
     </script> 
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  <!--end-rotating-images-->
   <div id="hero-cycle" class="clearfix">
      <div id="hero-nav">
        <ul>
          <script type="text/javascript">
              for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { // Start 3 Rotating Images 
               document.write("<li class='hero-text'>");
               document.write("<div class='hero-info clearfix'>");
               var linkValue = x[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
               var linkValue = x[i].getElementsByTagName("filePath")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
               document.write("<a href='" + linkValue + "' target='_blank'>");
               linkValue = x[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
               document.write(linkValue);
               document.write("</a>");
               // End description for Rotating Images
               document.write("</div>");
               document.write("<a class='page' href='#'></a></li>");
          }

       </script>
   </ul>
   <div id="annc_controls">
    <a href="#" id="play">
    <img src="images/blue_play.gif" alt="Play" border="0" style="vertical-align: text-bottom" /></a>
    <a href="#" id="pause">
    <img src="images/blue_pause.gif" alt="Stop" border="0" style="vertical-align: text-bottom" />
    </a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
```

XML file:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<homepage>
  <rotatingImages>
    <item>
      <image>manage/newImages/soldier-sunset.jpg</image>
      <description>My Test 1</description>
      <filePath>http://www.sigar.mil/newsroom/spotlight/12/2012-sep-05-sopko-visits-afghanistan.html </filePath>
    </item>
    <item>
      <image>manage/newImages/2012-04-03-jet.jpg</image>
      <description>My Test3</description>
      <filePath>http://www.sigar.mil/newsroom/spotlight/12/2012-sep-05-sopko-visits-afghanistan.html </filePath>
    </item>
    <item>
      <image>manage/newImages/sigar-brochre.jpg</image>
      <description>My Test2 </description>
      <filePath>http://www.sigar.mil/newsroom/spotlight/12/2012-sep-05-sopko-visits-afghanistan.html </filePath>
    </item>
  </rotatingImages>
 </homepage>`
```

Comment: Why don't you do that slider html generation serverside, e.g. with something powerful lik XSLT?

Comment: @useruser1636957: I said *serverside*, that does not need to be JavaScript

Comment: I didn't mean the one for the slide-animation (which of course happens clientside), but that `document.write`-mess with contents of a xml file.

Comment: Actually getting the content from the xml file works perfect.  I'm writting to the xml file from a .aspx using slq.  I will bang on this until I get it right.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: I found a solution see above.

Answer (score 0):

Since `rotator` and `cycle` elements are added dynamically, they don't exist when the page loads and the jQuery function runs. You need to delegate with `.on()` so that the handlers will be added when the elements are. For information on `.on`, see http://api.jquery.com/on/ and scroll down to the section on Direct and delegated events.

Another problem with your page is that you use the same ID each time through the for-loop. IDs have to be unique.  The repeated IDs are coming from this code:

```
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
   document.write("<div id='rotator'><div id='cycle' class='clearfix'><div class='entry clearfix'>");
```

Each time through the loop it adds DIVs with IDs 'rotator', 'cycle', 'hero-cycle', and 'hero-nav'.

Comment: .on()??? I'm pretty new with this. What is .on() function? And I can't find any repeating IDs.  I'm using, rotator, cycle, hero-cycle and hero-nav, am I missing something?

Comment: I removed the IDs from the code so my issue is with the JavaScript.  See my comments to Bergi above.

Comment: Now I'm having problems with the javascript displaying as a child node. Don't know how to hide it.  See my demo here: http://geewebsolution.com/demo.html

Answer (score 0):

Put the `jQuery('#cycle').cycle({ … });` code into the `jQuery(document).ready` function.

Comment: Looks like my issue also is with the DIV tags.  I tried putting the code into the jQuery(docuemtn).ready function and nothing.  What am I missing?

Comment: Check `jQuery('#cycle').length` (by alerting/logging). Did the selector match? And yes, as @Barmar mentioned, you can't output *unique* `id` attributes in a loop

Comment: Hm, then clean up your ids and use class selectors only

Comment: For some reason while rotating the 1st image is 2nd and the javascript i.e. "if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();" is displaying 1st. I'm only rotating 3 images. How can I hide the scirpt for window.XMLHttpRequest? It is not a browser thing because I get the same results in an older browser or maybe I'm using the wrong HttpRequest.

Comment: Um, array literals need square brackets. I'm also not sure what you want to do with those

Comment: I put them in an array because it repeats 3 times.  It's working correctly that is not the problem. This issue is how do I hide the JavaScript from the browser.  The code is showing in the page.  I found this tutorial http://www.ischool.utexas.edu/mirrors/LDP/LDP/LGNET/123/smith.html but it uses php and i'm using and xml document as the source.

Comment: Um, what do you mean by "*the code is showing in the page*"? Could you please link to your demo page?

Comment: Here is my demo page http://geewebsolution.com/demo.html.  You will see the XMLHttpRequest code first then after 5 seconds the rotating images will follow.  How do I hide the javascript code?

Comment: Actually, I don't see anything (only a console message `[cycle] terminating; too few slides: 1`). What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using IE9. When I use compatibility view it is blank. In IE9 I see the code.  Using FireFox it is blank also.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't see a slideshow, I see the following message in the Javascript console: `[cycle] terminating; too few slides: 1`

Comment: Check my demo now, you are able to see the code now. http://geewebsolution.com/demo.html

Comment: Wow, an awesome plugin :-) You will have to move the scripts outside the `div#cycle`, otherwise it will be recognized as one of its child nodes. Or fully remove it and do the xml->html transformation serverside…

Comment: Do you have a link or source to do it that way?  xml ->html transformation.  I'm new to this.

Comment: I tried using xsl to display the xml and the issue now is that the rotating images does not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
**SOLUTION:** I figured it out. I used jQuery instead of JavaScript with a little help from zohodiscussions.com.

Ajax Google plugin:  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js

**js. file:**
function form_input_classes() {

    jQuery('input[type="text"]').addClass('text');
    jQuery('input[type="password"]').addClass('text');
    jQuery('input[type="checkbox"]').addClass('checkbox');
    jQuery('input[type="radio"]').addClass('radiobutton');
    jQuery('input[type="submit"]').addClass('submit');
    jQuery('input[type="image"]').addClass('buttonImage');

}
function form_labelize() { jQuery(".labelize input:text").clearingInput(); }


var version = jQuery.browser.version;

if (version instanceof Object) { version = version.number(); }

function loadXMLDoc(XMLname) {
    return jQuery.ajax({ async: false, url: XMLname }).responseXML;
}
xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("demo.xml");
var M = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("rotatingImages");
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('script').remove()
    form_input_classes();
    form_labelize();
    var pauseClicked = function () {
        jQuery('#cycle').cycle('pause');
        jQuery('#play').attr("style", "display:block");
        jQuery('#pause').attr("style", "display:none");
        jQuery('#pause').removeClass("active");
        return false;
    };
    var playClicked = function () {
        jQuery('#cycle').cycle('resume');
        jQuery('#pause').attr("style", "display:block");
        jQuery('#play').attr("style", "display:none");
        jQuery('#pause').addClass("active");
        return false;
    };
    jQuery('#play').attr("style", "display:none");
    jQuery('#pause').attr("style", "display:block");
    jQuery('#pause').click(pauseClicked);
    jQuery('#play').click(playClicked);
    jQuery("#slideNavigation a").focus(function () {
        jQuery(this).blur();
    });


    jQuery('#cycle').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        speed: 1000,
        timeout: 5000,
        prev: '#prev',
        next: '#next',
        pager: '#hero-nav ul ',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function (idx, slide) {
            return '#hero-nav li:eq(' + idx + ') a.page';
        }
    });

})


**HTML references:**
<div id="content" class="clearfix home">
  <div id="hero">
    <div id='rotator'>
      <div id='cycle' class='clearfix'>
       <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(M).find('image').each(function (i, img) {
        document.write("<img src='" + jQuery(img).text() + "' />");
        })
       </script>
      </div>
    </div>

     <!--end-rotating-images-->
       <div id="hero-cycle" class="clearfix">
        <div id="hero-nav">
         <ul>
          <script type="text/javascript">
           jQuery(M).each(function (i, item){
           document.write("<li class='hero-text'>");
           document.write("<div class='hero-info clearfix'>");
           document.write("<a href='" +
     jQuery(item).find('filePath').text() + "' target='_blank'>" +
     jQuery(item).find('description').text()
     + "</a>");
           document.write("</div>")
           document.write("<a class='page' href='#'></a></li>")
          })
          </script>

      </ul>
      <div id="annc_controls">
         <a href="#" id="play">
         <img src="images/blue_play.gif" alt="Play" border="0" style="vertical-align: text-bottom"/></a>
         <a href="#" id="pause">
         <img src="images/blue_pause.gif" alt="Stop" border="0" style="vertical-align: text-bottom"/>
         </a>
      </div>
      <!--<div id="slideNavigation"></div>-->
      </div>
      <!-- /#hero-nav -->
      </div>
      <!-- /#hero-cycle -->
      </div>
      <!-- /#hero -->
      </div>
```